# how to get lowest value to turn red and back to black when it gets higher?

Tags: javascript, css

im trying to make a script to turn the lowest value to red and back to black when it gets higer again.

```js
function findLowest() {
  // Get the input elements
  var value1 = document.getElementById("value1");
  var value2 = document.getElementById("value2");
  var value3 = document.getElementById("value3");

  // Find the lowest number value
  var lowestValue = Math.min(parseInt(value1.value), parseInt(value2.value), parseInt(value3.value));

  // Check which element has the lowest number value and add the "lowest" class to it
  if (parseInt(value1.value) === lowestValue) {
    value1.classList.add('lowest');
  } else if (parseInt(value2.value) === lowestValue) {
    value2.classList.add('lowest');
  } else if (parseInt(value3.value) === lowestValue) {
    value3.classList.add('lowest');
  }
}
```

```css
.lowest {
  color: red;
}

input:not(.lowest) {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="value1">Value 1:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value1" name="value1" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
  <br>
  <label for="value2">Value 2:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value2" name="value2" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
  <br>
  <label for="value3">Value 3:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value3" name="value3" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
</form>
```

[image]

i got this to work but i cant get it back to black. my goal with this is to create a result tab on the left where it points out the lowest number with red.
not in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the values all back to black in the beginning of the function should leave you with only one red number at the end of it.

```
function findLowest() {
  // Get the input elements
  var value1 = document.getElementById("value1");
  var value2 = document.getElementById("value2");
  var value3 = document.getElementById("value3");

  // Remove class "lowest" to turn all numbers black
  value1.classList.remove('lowest');
  value2.classList.remove('lowest');
  value3.classList.remove('lowest');

  // Find the lowest number value
  var lowestValue = Math.min(parseInt(value1.value), parseInt(value2.value), parseInt(value3.value));

  // Check which element has the lowest number value and add the "lowest" class to it
  if (parseInt(value1.value) === lowestValue) {
    value1.classList.add('lowest');
  } else if (parseInt(value2.value) === lowestValue) {
    value2.classList.add('lowest');
  } else if (parseInt(value3.value) === lowestValue) {
    value3.classList.add('lowest');
  }
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that one of the inputs need to be a text/name then it wont work right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by remove the `lowest` class from all inputs before doing anything in the function, and then determine the new lowest to give it the class, and this is the simple but big way.

---

To take a short and clear way, just do that:

```js
function findLowest() {
  var inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]")]
  let values = inputs.map(input => input.value)
  var lowest = Math.min(...values)

  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.classList[ input.value == lowest ? "add" : "remove" ]("lowest")
  })
}
```

```css
.lowest { color: red; }

input:not(.lowest) { color: black; }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="value1">Value 1:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value1" name="value1" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
  <br>
  <label for="value2">Value 2:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value2" name="value2" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
  <br>
  <label for="value3">Value 3:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="value3" name="value3" oninput="findLowest()"><br>
  <label for="value4">Value 4 => "text":</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="value4" name="value4"><br>
</form>
```

We're getting the inputs as an array, then get the values of the inputs with the `map` method, then get the lowest value with `Math.min` method, and finally loop over all inputs using the `forEach` method, and conditionally choose to add or remove the `lowest` class from the input that has the lowest value.

Comment: i forgot to mention that one of the inputs need to be a text/name then it wont work right?

Comment: @Oleee I updated the answer, it's just `document.querySelectorAll("input[type=number]")` which adds attribute selector to you selection.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that ?
Use:
A- `.valueAsNumber` to get a `input[type=number]` number value ( not a string)
B- `classList.toggle` with it force boolean argument
C- event `input` directly on the `form` (not on each element)

```js
const 
  myForm = document.forms['my-form']
, inNums = [...myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=number]')]
  ;
myForm.oninput = event =>
  {
  let min = inNums.reduce((min,el)=>Math.min(el.valueAsNumber, min), Infinity);
  inNums.forEach( el => el.classList.toggle('lowest', el.value == min));
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
.lowest {
  color : red; 
  }
label, input {
  display : block;
  }
label  {
  font-size : .8rem;
  margin    : .8rem
  }
input {
  font-size : 1rem;
  padding   : 0 0 0 0.5em;
  width     : 6rem;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <label>Value 1: 
    <input type="number" name="value1" value="0" > 
  </label>
  <label>Value 2:
    <input type="number" name="value2" value="0"> 
  </label> 
  <label>Value 3:
    <input type="number"  name="value3" value="0">
  </label> 
</form>
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that one of the inputs need to be a text/name then it wont work right?

Comment: @you especially forgot to read the useful recommendations before posting here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
The code you mention only has number inputs, why not put text inputs to replace them all? be more specific in the future, you will save others from wasting time writing useless answers.